# scrapy login form problems

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to login with scrapy using FormRequest and get redirected to the search link.

This is part of my code:

```
start_urls = ['https://www.cpaelites.com/member.php?action=login']


def parse(self, response):
    payload = {'username':'','password':''}
    r = [FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata=payload,callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self,response):
   if "incorrect" in response.body:
           self.logger.error("Login failed")
           return

   elif "Login to your Account" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Try again")
            return
   else:
            url = "https://www.cpaelites.com/search.php"
            results = FormRequest(url,formdata={'keywords': 'bitter'},callback=self.parse_page)
            return results

def parse_page(self, response):
    #do the rest
```

It doesn't give me any errors when I start my crawler, it just ends.

2nd Question:
How can I login in scrapy shell and go to a specific search page so I can get the xpath?

Comment: _"when i start my crawler...it just ends."_: you may want to share scrapy logs to show that. Indeed, using scrapy shell to login is a good option. Just run `scrapy shell 'https://www.cpaelites.com/member.php?action=login'` and then something like `fetch(scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response((response,formdata=payload))`

Comment: Post a complete run log either through pastebin or append them to your question

Answer (score 0):

in `after_login` method you forgot to `yield` `FormRequest`

maybe you wanted to do something like

```
def parse(self, response):
   payload = {'username':'some user','password':'some password'}
   yield FormRequest.from_response(
       response,formdata=payload,callback=self.after_login
   )
```